# Python: Count the First Instance of each Unique Value in a Column with Repeating Values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

First post here so apologies if this is unclear.  I have a pandas dataframe and am trying to return a 1 for the first instance of each unique value in a column, and return a 0 for each repeating value after the first unique instance.

In Excel I've used the below formula but on a larger dataframe it becomes untenable.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)=1,1,0)

ID  Unique
ABC1    1
ABC1    0
ABC1    0
ABC2    1
ABC3    1
ABC3    0
ABC4    1
```

Comment: `df['Unique'] = df['ID'].duplicated()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the negation of [duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df['unique'] = (~df.ID.duplicated()).astype(int)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
     ID  unique
0  ABC1       1
1  ABC1       0
2  ABC1       0
3  ABC2       1
4  ABC3       1
5  ABC3       0
6  ABC4       1
```

Comment: @bs777 Glad I could help. If you found my answer helpful, please consider marking it as accepted. It also signals others that your issue was solved.